# Website reload when call parent set state

Tags: reactjs, callback, parent-child

I created a child component and want to change parent state by a parameter from textbox in child when click a button in child either. I pass the function to the child component. After click button, the state changed, html content changed but after that the website reload and the state change back to initial value.

This is main class

```
class Main extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
             samples: 5
        };
    }
    setSamplesHandler(value) {    
        this.setState({samples: value})
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <ControlBoard status={status} setSamplesHandler={this.setSamplesHandler.bind(this)}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Main;
```

This is child class

```
class ControlBoard extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            tempSamples: 0
        };
    }
    changeTextBox(){
        this.setState({tempSamples: event.target.value})
    }
    onClickSet() {
        this.props.setSamplesHandler(this.state.tempSamples);
    }
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder={this.props.status.samples} aria-label="set" onChange={this.changeTextBox.bind(this)}/>
                <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" onClick={this.onClickSet.bind(this)}>Set</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default ControlBoard;
```

Please help me !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button is inside a form, so the default browser behaviour is to reload the browser when it is clicked.

You can prevent this by invoking the `preventDefault` method on the event.

```js
onClickSet(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.props.setSamplesHandler(this.state.tempSamples);
}
```

Comment: it works, thank you, i kind of thinking about this but i wasn't clear